# Saving category to a post, before publishing the post

Tags: posts, categories

I have created a link from the dashboard, which goes to add new post, but with a category already selected for the post - but the post will not belong to this category before publishing - this is a problem, because I have some custom fields, which I have assigned to the category, and they will not be visible before the post is published.

Is there a way to asign a category to a post, before it is published, which will make what I am trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [wp_set_post_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) to set a category before the post is published. You need to get the post_id by call the global variable `$post` and get the id by `$post->ID`.

Here is a simple example. Change the id (2) to the id of your wanted category.

```
function wpse_78701_add_category_before_post() {
    global $post;
    if( $post->ID ) {
        wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, 2, 'category' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'wpse_78701_add_category_before_post');
```

**Update**

If you want to change the category that will be saved when the user clicks on the link you have to add something like `?cat=2` on the dashboard-links like this:

```
echo '<a href="post-new.php?cat=1">'. __('Add new post in category X', 'theme') .'</a>';
```

Then you can get the category bu use `$_GET['cat'];` like this:

```
function wpse_78701_add_category_before_post() {
    global $post;

    // Get category-ID from the link in dashboard (cat=X)
    $category = ( isset( $_GET['cat'] ) ? $_GET['cat'] : '' );

    if( isset( $post ) && $post->ID ) {
        wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, $category, 'category' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'wpse_78701_add_category_before_post');
```

Comment: thank you! How would I link to it, from the dashboard for it to work? My current method does not work with this

Comment: You only need to add this to your functions.php file. Then this will add a category to new posts. (Is there a way to asign a category to a post, before it is published)

Comment: ah ok, but this will set the same category for all posts I add, right? I am trying to create links from the dashboard for my client to create a post in a certain category without having to select the category.

This I have done - but I have different fields assigned to each category, which are not visible untill the post is published (and thereby saved in the category).

SO I want to somehow save the post to the category, and thereby making my fields for that category visible, before the user publishes the post.